# Rewire client side events wired by jQuery on reloading the UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, updatepanel, webforms

I have a repeater in an updatepanel, in the repeater there are several panels.
The panels are different in ways, but they have one common css class, so I wire their onclick, onmouseover and onmouseout event with jQuery on the $(document).ready

But after a partial postback of the updatepanel update these wires are lost and I cant find a place to put these wires back in.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".actionicon_normal").click(function () {
        ClickActionIcon($(this));
    });
    $(".actionicon_normal").hover(function () {
        HoverActionIcon($(this));
    }, function () {
        OutActionIcon($(this));
    });
    $(".actionicon_normal").each(function (i) {
        var chk = $(this).find("input");
        var backpos = $(this).css("background-position").split(" ");
        if (chk.attr("checked")) {
            $(this).css("background-position", backpos[0] + " -" + $(this).height() + "px");
        }
    });
})
```

as you can see I modify the background position in $(".actionicon_normal").each.
I need a place to run a the same after the updatepanel is updated.
I tried to experiment with .ajaxComplete, but was unable to find a proper solution.

Another way would be to wire these in the codebehind, but I cannot get a hold of all the actionicons, as the ItemDataBind only urns on first load, plus even in ItemCreated I'm not able to get a hold of all these divs having one same css class, plus there is a CheckBox in the div which I need to check for the checked value and I was not able to do that either. So if the server side is a better way, I would need a lot of help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page might help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx

The following method is triggered by the Script manager every time the page is loaded, you are only concerned about partial postbacks so it also check this

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {

        }
    }
```